# Erro ao rodar minha aplicação MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Esse é o erro:

```cs
Linha 1:  
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Util.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Eu havia criado um outro projeto chamado Util e começou a dar esse problema. O que fiz, removi o projeto e continua. Mas no meu Global.asax agora está assim:

```cs
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Ruptura.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Como eu resolvo isso? Esse é o erro completo:

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
Erro do Analisador
Descrição: Erro ao analisar um recurso necessário para atender esta solicitação.
Examine os detalhes específicos do erro de análise e modifique o arquivo de origem 
apropriadamente.     
Mensagem de Erro do Analisador: Não foi possível carregar o tipo 'Util.MvcApplication'.    
Erro de Origem:
    Linha 1:
    <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Util.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
Arquivo de Origem: /global.asax Linha: 1
Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319;
    Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34009
```

É todo o projeto, mas posto a minha ***View*** e a ***Master*** dela,

***View***:

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Acao";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
}
<h2>Acao</h2>   
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="txtCnpjPdv">UF:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" id="txtCnpjPdv" 
                placeholder="Digite o Cnpj" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E o layout dela(Master):

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Util.js")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Pedidos", "Index", "Home", null, new { 
                  @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Laboratórios Ltda</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Ficou pior!
Vi que o projeto **Util** estava no *path* e deletei de vez e agora aparece esse um erro. Me parece que em algum lugar do IISExpress ele está sendo solicitado e não há nada dele mais, do **Util**:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
A página solicitada não pode ser acessada porque os dados de configuração 
relacionados à página são inválidos.

Informações detalhadas do erro:
Módulo             IIS Web Core
Notificação        Desconhecido
Manipulador        Ainda não determinado
Código do erro     0x80070003
Erro de Configuração       Não é possível ler o arquivo de configuração
Arquivo de Configuração    \\?\D:\Projetos ACHÉ\Ruptura\Util\web.config
URL solicitada             http://localhost:53130/
Caminho físico
Método de logon    Ainda não determinado
Usuário de logon   Ainda não determinado
Diretório de Rastreamento de Solicitação: 
    C:\Users\Paulo\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\
Origem da Configuração:
   -1: 
    0:
```

**Mais informações**:

Este erro ocorre quando há um problema na leitura do arquivo de configuração do servidor Web ou do aplicativo Web. Em alguns casos, os logs de eventos podem conter mais informações sobre a causa deste erro.

Se você vir o texto "Há uma seção `'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler'` duplicada definida", esse erro aconteceu porque você está executando um aplicativo baseado no **.NET Framework 3.5** no **.NET Framework 4**. Se você estiver executando o ***WebMatrix***, para resolver este problema, vá para o nó Configurações para definir a versão do ***.NET Framework*** como ".NET 2". Também é possível remover as seções extras do arquivo web.config.

Comment: Posta o cabeçalho do seu código c# (codebehind)

Comment: Eu dei um Find em toda a solution e não encontrei essa linha: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Util.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>. Onde pode estar essa linha para eu corrigir?

Comment: Então, está linha costuma ficar no topo do documento asp.net, antes do doctype. O que vc fez quando criou o novo projeto? Copiou e colou código? Você provavelmente puxou informações com o namespace do outro projeto e por isso ele está procurando por um arquivo que ele não pode encontrar.

Comment: Antes do DocType não tenho nada em nenhuma das minhas views.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo jeito ai, o seu exemplo mostra que você está atribuindo um namespace para "Inherits" e você deve atribuir a Classe que fica dentro do Global.asax.cs

veja o meu exemplo:

em Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyMvcApplication.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

em Global.asax.cs

```
namespace MyMvcApplication{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema.
O arquivo de extensão "csproj" ("NomeDoArquivo.csproj") não estava criando as referencias das telas novas.

Então, reiniciei o PC, para poder forçar a parada de todas as execuções de programas abertos, abri o arquivo .csproj, e criei a referencia manualmente no arquivo e salvei, conforme a própria IDE faz.

EXEMPLO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  ...

 <Content Include="NomePastaDoArquivo\NomeDoArquivo.aspx" />

  ...

 <Compile Include="NomePastaDoArquivo\NomeDoArquivo.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>NomeDoArquivo.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="NomePastaDoArquivo\NomeDoArquivo.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>NomeDoArquivo.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
```

Answer (score 0):

É muito simples para resolver esse problema: você precisa renomear o campo `Inherits`, pois ele esta tentando herdar de uma classe que não existe ou que foi renomeado o `namespace`, ou que esteja faltando essa DLL no seu projeto:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Ruptura.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```